Is it possible to tune the diff pair length in CircuitMaker?
I`m trying to use CircuitMaker (CM 2.2.1) to make a PCB with differential pairs. Is it practically possible to tune the length of the diff pair in CM? In Altium there is a special tool 'Interactive Diff Pair Length Tuning'. And it seems to me that there is nothing similar in CircuitMaker.
Are there any tips how to do this issue in CM?

What response did you get when you asked this question on the appropriate  circuit maker forum? What did you find in the documentation that wasn't much help?

The same question was asked on CircuitMaker forum 2 years ago and there was only one answer with help-link that doesn't really help because unfortanutely there is nothing about the length tuning in CircuitMaker documentation. So as I guess this feature is unavailable there (despite the fact that it's described on CM home page).
